# [Playwright]Is there any way to turn “Chrome automated test”off? I'm afraid the website detected this and blocked me

Tags: chromium, playwright

[Playwright]Is there any way to turn “Chrome automated test”off? I'm afraid the website detected this and blocked me.

I’m using  `playwright.chromium.launch_persistent_context()`
[This is what I want to disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc2X4.jpg).By the way,I found that when I use`playwright.chromium.launch（）`，there won‘t be this title anymore but I want non incognito instead of incognito

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Chromium, or add options to disable infobar
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype

```
options.args("disable-infobars");
```